# Сборщик скриптов (inline script) в темплейтах django в один js файл

Tags: javascript, django

Изучаю Django пишу небольшой проект, не знаю, как сделать удобнее работу и правильно.

В идеале хочу, чтобы в каждом html файле темплейта можно было прописывать кусок script, (обычно работающий с DOM элементами этого темплейта), который может брать и выполнять функции и переменные из js скриптов другого темплейта или общего script.js.

В общем интуитивно понимаю что должны быть какие то сборщики-упаковщики кода с разделением контекстов и т.п.
Ребят, подскажите как я могу осуществить такую задачу?

В данный момент пробую объявить в base.html блок для js скриптов, обернутый в `<script></script>` и в соответствующем блоке в других темплейтах дополняю его js кодом (после `{{ block.super }}` ). Из минусов - так не получается делать когда инклудишь темплейты. (получается что block дублируется)

Comment: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor

Comment: Пропробовал - этот плагин объединяет только то, что внутри его тэгов. Сколько пар тэгов - столько файлов и будет. В настройках не нашел функции объединения всего в один файл.

Comment: У него в документации, на сколько я помню, есть упоминание [django-sekizai](https://github.com/divio/django-sekizai), в паре с которым он порождает один css-файл и один js-файл.

Comment: Спасибо!! Подойдет для решения. Однако жаль, что в этом плагине нельзя render_block ставить внутри блока.